# Provide default values for html form, with option to change values before $_POST

Tags: php, html

I am currently creating an html form on a web page, and i was wondering if there was a way to add default values to the text boxes, but the user could also just delete the default text and enter in new text if he needed to???

What i currently have is this...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      Suspend: <input type="text" name="sus"><br />
      Device Name: <input type="text" name="dev"><br />
      IP: <input type="text" name="ip"><br />
      Dependency: <input type="text" value="none" name="depend"><br />
      Email: <input type="email" value="abc@123.com" name="email">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['sumbit']))
 {
   $sus=$_POST['sus'];
   $dev=$_POST['dev'];
   $ip=$_POST['ip'];
   $depend=$_POST['depend'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];

    if(isset($sus) && isset($dev) && isset($ip) && isset($depend) && isset($email)
     {
       $update=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET Suspend=$sus, Device=$dev, IP=$ip,   Dependence=$depend, Email=$email WHERE id=$id");
      }
 }
```

With the email and dependency fields, they will be the default values 95% of the time, but not all the time, and my boss wants default values supplied for them, but also wants them to be able to change them... I then perform mysql queries with these $_POST results to update the database... right now, even if you change the text in the field in the form, it still enters in the default values in the database.. i need it to where if they do not change the default value, then the default value will be added to the database... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you adding it to the database?  Even if the value is `abc@123.com` if you change it *that* should be what is posted

Comment: This is a SQL injection waiting to happen.  You need to validate/sanitize $_POST!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value inside of php like that

```
$value = $_POST['email'];
```

If you typed something into the input box you will get the value insted of the default value.

If you work with **html5** you need to use the **placeholder attr**, take a look here then:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has the new Placeholder attribute of the INPUT tag, but this value goes away when you type on the field.  The INPUT tag also has the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try to look at this: [Placeholders](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)

Placeholders are default text that is shown inside the input.
But if a user does not insert anything placeholder value is not included to the post when the form is submmited. The `value=""` will still be recognized.

Comment: i actually need to default value to be posted if they do not change it... sorry, i probably wasnt clear enough in the explanation... for some reason the code i have just always inserts the default value, even if you change it

Comment: Well you could just put a value inside your input. for example `Suspend: <input type="text" name="sus" value="default value"><br />`

Comment: Or may be you dont want to display the default value? if not, you can validate the input on post `if(empty($_POST['sus'])){ $_POST['sus']== "default value"; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since the placeholder attr is still fairly new and not supported with older browsers, here is a fallback that can be used to provide the same functionality as the placeholder attr.

```
if (!("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"))) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[placeholder]"),
        input,
        dateDefault;

    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
         input = inputs[i];
         input.value = input.getAttribute("placeholder");

         input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
             dateDefault = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
             (this.value === dateDefault) && (this.value === "");
         }, false);
         input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
             (this.value === "") && (this.value === dateDefault);
         }, false);
    }
}
```

If the placeholder attr isn't available, it uses the value that you put for the placeholder attr and assigns it to the value. Then using some js you can detect if the input field is empty or still has the original value, or if the user has typed. You can easily adapt this to jQuery or using addEventListener, attachEvent or whatever means you need to support the browsers you need. Hope this helps!